# Extract the matched regex or delete strings other than the matched regex

Tags: regex, perl, extract

I have a file

```
**data2.l**
I have a car 
its nissan GTR 
this car is super fast
```

If I want to delete the word "car" from this file I just use

```
perl -p -i -e "s/car//ig" data2.l
```

But if I want to keep "car" and delete all other terms other than "car"
If I try to just extract the "car" I am just able to extract the complete line containing "car".

```
**example O/P**
car
car
```

So can this one-liner be modified a bit to do this task?

Comment: What if the word 'car' appears multiple times on each line? What would you like your output to be then?

Comment: Print both the times. Irrespective of the number of time it repeats i just want to extract that word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Perl does something similar, but all the "car"s on the same line stay on the same line:

```
  perl -lne 'print join " ", /car\S*/ig if /car/i'
```

You get this output from steve's example:

```
car
car123 Car
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Mark .. i was trying to modify your  solution to obtain the output as "car123" as well if their exists a string with name "car123". I could only manage to extract the whole line. but not just that "car123"

Comment: Not sure I understand.  So if there is a word that contains "car" as part of it, you want the whole word printed out?  Not just the string "car", and not the whole line?

Comment: Yes i want the whole word printed and not the whole line

Comment: @steve  thanks.  swapped out the negated char class for the perl non-whitespace expression `\S`.

Answer (score 3):

If the word 'car' appears multiple times on each line, this will literally print both times, adding a newline ending:

```
grep -io "car" file.txt
```

Input:

```
i have a car 
its nissan GTR 
this car is super fast Car
```

Output:

```
car
car
Car
```

**UPDATE:**

```
grep -ioP "car[^ ]*" file.txt
```

input:

```
i have a car 
its nissan GTR 
this car123 is super fast Car
```

output:

```
car
car123
Car
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @steve .. i was trying to obtain the edited output from the edited input from ur solution. But i was not succesful. So how can i modify to get the output as shown in ur solution. I.e. if i have car123 in the file i want to extract that as well as car123. How can i do it

Comment: @unkaitha: Please see the update. It uses the Perl regex engine to match the word car and anything after it, any number of times, just as long as it's not a space.

Answer (score 0):

I had some fun with this.  All of these options will only print car once, even if it occurs multiple times in the file.

```
more data2.1 | grep -q 'car' && echo 'car'

more dara2.1 | sed -n 'h;N;$x;$s/.*car.*/car/p'

perl -ne '$i=1 if ~~/car/}{print "car\n" if $i' data2.1
```

Comment: Upon further inspection, it appears what I provided you with is not what you were looking for. `perl -ne '@i = m/(car\S*)/g;$,="\n";print @i;print"\n"if@i' data2.1` will do it, though.